# Max-width/height without stretching smaller images?

Tags: html, css

I have modal images on my site, and I have set a max-size (in the css code) on them so they're not too big when opened up.
But, I also have some images that are smaller than my set max-size, and these are now getting stretched out when clicking on them. I don't want that. I want them to stay in their original size, even though they're small.

How do I do this?

This is the html and css (and Javascript) I've been using:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Is there something in there that's stretching out my smaller images?

Comment: `max-width` isn’t going to stretch anything on its own. Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: max sizes won't distort the image as @Ry- has said so there must be something else affecting the images presentation. However, it would be useful to know how you are setting max-width and max-height (?e.g. in relation to the viewport or an absolute size?).

Comment: I just used the one from here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

First warp the images into a  `<div> </div>`

Then set that min-width to the div not the images

css

```
.wrapper {
min-width:; /*set min width*/
max-width:; /*set max width*/
}
.wrapper img{
width:100%;
object-fit:contain;
}
```

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
<img src="image.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the max width and height for images then they will not exceed those but if the image's natural dimensions are both smaller they wont expand (unlike if you had set width or height). There will be no stretching or distortion, just larger images will be show smaller than their natural size.

This snippet shows images of various natural dimensions with their 'limited' versions following - the max width and height having been set as the smaller of 50% of the viewport dimensions and an absolute pixel size.

```css
img.limited {
  max-width: min(50vw, 500px);
  max-height: min(50vh, 250px);
}
```

```html
max-width = min(50vw, 500px);<br> max-height = min(50vh, 250px);<br>

<br>img dimensions 100 x 150<br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/150" />
<img class="limited" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/100/150" />
<br>img dimensions 1000 x 300<br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1000/300" />
<img class="limited" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/1000/300" />
<br>img dimensions 200 x 200<br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/200" />
<img class="limited" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/200" />
<br>img dimensions 300 x 1000<br>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/300/1000" />
<img class="limited" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1019/300/1000" />
```